# Creating a fake image for a CKEditor custom Plugin

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I am developing a plugin for video embedding, I put this code when the plugin dialog OK button is clicked.

```
var embedCode = 
    '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html"' +
        width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + textField + '?rel=0"' +
        frameborder="0" width="620" height="200" style="width:' + width + 'px; height:' + height + 'px">' +
    '</iframe>';

this.getParentEditor().insertHtml(embedCode);
```

Now when double click on the iframe in the editor open the iframe properties dialog not my plugin dialog.

How I can develop a fake image for my custom plugin.

Comment: How did it go on this? Where you able to insert a fake image?

Comment: In ck editor when you insert an image. The image actually is shown in the editor in the form of a fake element. And the fake element is actually an image. In case of image it is image selected but you can change the fake element by using the API. The actually source will be the exact image. Fake element is for the purpose to edit or select and delete the element in the editor design view. In source view the exact code will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for it.
Ckeditor make fake elements from the code generated by the plugins. When the editor loads it takes the code and convert it to fake elements and the default editing is worked on that fake elements the code for it will be defined in the

```
afterInit : function( editor )
    {
```

function of the the editor and will be called in on OK event of the edior

```
onOk : function()
{
    var embedCode = updatePreview( this,true );
    var newFakeImage = editor.createFakeElement( embedCode, 'cke_audio', 'audio', true  );
```

The Code for the fake element example is the following, I have created for an audio embed code plugin

```
afterInit : function( editor )
    {
        function createFakeElement( editor, realElement )
        {
            return editor.createFakeParserElement( realElement, 'cke_audio', 'audio', true );
        }

        var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
                dataFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.dataFilter;
            if ( dataFilter )
            {
                dataFilter.addRules(
                    {
                        elements :
                        {
                            'div' : function( element )
                            {
                                //alert("here");
                                var attributes = element.attributes;

                                if( attributes.class == 'audio' ){
                                    //alert("here");
                                    return createFakeElement( editor, element );
                                }
                                return null;

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    5);
            }
        }
```